# Mathjax in HTML: Cannot select equations

Tags: html, mathjax

I am using Mathjax to display equations in an HTML. This is my code:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <title>Math in HTML</title>
    
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <script>
    MathJax = {
      tex: {
        inlineMath: [['$', '$'], ['\\(', '\\)']]
      },
      svg: {
        fontCache: 'global'
      }
    };
    </script>
    <script src="https://polyfill.io/v3/polyfill.min.js?features=es6"></script>
    <script id="MathJax-script" async src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/mathjax@3/es5/tex-mml-chtml.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
        <h1>Mathematic equations</h1>
        <p>I cannot select this equation:
                
                $$\intop_0^1f(x)dx=\pi$$
            
            nor this one $x^2 + 3x - 2 = \zeta$.
        </p>
</body>

</html>
```

The problem is that I cannot select the equations. Previously I was using this in the header:

```html
        <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.mathjax.org/mathjax/latest/MathJax.js?config=TeX-AMS-MML_HTMLorMML"></script> 
        <script type="text/x-mathjax-config">                                                                                         
            MathJax.Hub.Config({                                                                                                      
                tex2jax: {                                                                                                            
                  inlineMath: [ ['$','$'], ["\\(","\\)"] ],                                                                           
                  processEscapes: true                                                                                                
                }                                                                                                                     
            });                                                                                                                       
        </script>
```

which produces "selectable equations" but raises a deprecation warning. (I tried to insert another snippet with this working example but StackOverflow complained it was too much code.)

I cannot find out how to convert the equations into "selectable".

Answer (score 2):

You are correct that MathJax output can't be copied directly from the page in version 3.  Version 3 uses CSS with `content` properties in order to insert the characters into the page, and `content` text is not selectable in the page.

In general, copying MathJax output would only be reliable with the simplest of expressions (nothing involving super- or subscripts, fractions, roots, arrays, multi-character stretchy delimiters, accents, etc.), so this was never a supported feature for MathJax.

On the other hand, it would be possible for MathJax to insert the characters directly rather than use `content` CSS, and an extension to implement that would be possible.  [Example code for doing that](https://groups.google.com/g/mathjax-users/c/1BzTQFINbqY/m/xGYAlhDNAwAJ) is available in the MathJax User's Forum.

Comment: Is it possible to make it selectable and when you copy-paste you get the Latex code? I am aware of some websites doing this (don't have any example in mind now).

Comment: @user171780, the first code link in my message above gives the ability to copy the original LaTeX (though it is still not visibly selected).  Perhaps that is what you are looking for?